# Ck Editor Customization with Image2 plugin

Tags: javascript, c#, php, html

I am working on a **Ck Editor Customization** with **Image2 plugin (Version 4.6).**

> I am trying to set width in percentage , by default it allow only
>   pixels.

Is is possible to set percentage of width, and scale image keeping aspect ratio in image property popup window, Currently it is allow only width px.

Anyone has any good idea with this? thank you